# Oracle Rownum, get nth row

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I get the nth(2nd) row from a list of results and if the 2nd row (column 2) is a certain number do not print anything.

```
Select * from
(select s.id_numeric,
         s.client_id,
         s.depth,
         s.fas_sample_type,
         s.profile_number,
         Count(1) over() as cnt
  from   sample s 
  where  s.client_id = upper ('128336A') 
  and    s.id_numeric between 12325 and 12327
  and    s.fas_sample_type = sample_pkg.get_soil_sample
  and    s.status = sample_pkg.get_authorised_sample
  and    s.flg_released = constant_pkg.get_true)
Where cnt > 1
```

Comment: use row_number function and find the max number -1.

Comment: "nth" row according to what sort criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I thought it would be easy but it took me about 10 minutes to solve.

```
select * 
  from (select rownum row_num, 
               /* here_goes_rest_of_subquery */ 
         fetch first 2 rows only) sub_q
  where ...
  order by sub_q.row_num desc
  fetch first 1 row only;
```

Please note your subquery has no "order by" part and you want the nth row of the result. Thus you may end up getting different results on different clients.

Comment: What does go into the where clause

Comment: @user2713535 "Where cnt > 1"  goes into. Same as in your query.

So, only the subquery goes between brackets.